# Автоматическое резервное копирование файлов проекта VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio-2017, резервное-копирование

Есть ли аналог резервного копирования файлов проекта в VisualStudio аналогичный Delphi? (в Delphi в папке с проектом скрытая папка `__history` с файлами с расширением `.~номерРевизии~`)

Answer (score 0):

Вообще студия с git-ом хорошо интегрируется (даже локально, без сервака). Будет история изменений, локальные комиты итд.
Правой кнопкой на Solution -> Add solution to source control

Comment: А если проект уже коммитится (вручную) на сервер, добавление автоматического локального git будет нормально с этим жить?